# in java convert json object where parameter name is a value to a java opject or jpa entity

Tags: java, json, pojo

basically taking in a json object via a post api thats like the following

```
{
    [
        param_name: "name", 
        param_value: "jason"
        param_type: "varchar"
    ],
    [ 
        param_name: "age", 
        param_value: "15"
        param_type: "varchar"
    ]
}
```

then i want to convert it to a predefined java object where the parameter names are the same as the "param_value" values.

Is there anyway to do this in java, with a method like this?

```
student.setparamname(object.get("param_name"),object.get("param_value") );
```

Comment: Yes there are plenty of ways, but it entirely depends on which json library you use, and which methods it has avaliable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) and see the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/json/api/com/oracle/json/JsonObject.html) `JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");` and `String name = array.getJsonObject(0).getString("param_name");`

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this if my interpretation of your question is correct. This allows you to `POST` to the endpoint with an object and specify name and age in `json` format. I'm going to say that the above is a `Student` for example but that's just an example object. If you want to include validation have a look at using `@Valid`. What you've declared in the question is a `JsonArray` (indicated by the `[]` after the `{}`) within a `JsonObject` but there is no need for that, just create the `JsonObject` with the fields you require.

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = NewStudent.Builder.class)
    public class NewStudent{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    //getters and setters here
    //create builder here
    }

   public class Student{
private String name;
private String age;
//getters and setters here
}


@PostMapping(value = "/addstudent", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent(@RequestBody NewStudent newStudent){
Student student = new Student();
student.setName(newStudent.getName());
student.setAge(newStudent.getAge());
ResponseEntity<Student> responseContent = ResponseEntity.body(student);
return responseContent;
```

}

Comment: this isnt really what im asking, the input isnt a student object json,  its just a list of param values and parameter values, and i want to create a  populate a student object whose variable names = the param name values exactly from the json exactly.